# Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I cannot understand what is the problem in my Python code. It gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    main();
  File "main.py", line 67, in main
    count -= 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

Here is part of the code

I defined global variable

```
count = 3
```

then I created method main

```
def main():
    f = open(filename, 'r')

    if f != None:
        for line in f:

            #some code here

            count -= 1
            if count == 0: 
                break
```

what may be wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to tell `main()` that `count` is global.

Comment: (add `global count` to the first line of the main function)

Comment: Best way would be to skip using global variables and to work with a function parameter and a return value instead. See: [Why are global variables evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, it's a clear duplicate. (I've continued working on the question in a way that makes this more obvious.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`count -= 1` is equivalent to `count = count - 1`.  `count` is being evaluated before it's defined locally. When this happens you'll want to explicitly set the scope of `count` within the function as [global](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) (i.e. defined outside the function).

```
def main():
    global count
```