# Python Cron Job with Schedule not working

Tags: python, scope, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to repeat a function very 2 minutes  on a list and move every time one element further of the list. I use the 'schedule'  to do the task. The script is the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    machines_queue=[[...],[...],...] # list of the sublists
    global counter
    counter=   0

    def job(sub_list):
        somefunction(sub_list) # here I want each 2 min  iteration a sublist from machine_queue further  
        counter= counter +1    # here is pop the Error on the counter  
        print("I'm working...")

    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job,sub_list= machines_queue[counter])
    print(counter)


    while True :
        schedule.run_pending()`
```

The first time it goes well , them I get an  on the counter this Error:

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment."

I don't understand because I set  before the variable as  global so I don't get the scope issue.

If you have an idea please ....  :) Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720607/python-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-count-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution to do a task every to minutes  with various functions and conditions in this task: just do a normal loop as usual and add a  time sleep at the end, ( ex: time.sleep(120) .Then wrap the all code in a function / main  and use Schedule library on it if you still need it ....

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `global` statement inside the function you want to allow access to the variable. Move `global counter` to the beginning of the `job` function and it would work.

Comment: Just figured it out then I saw you post! glad I was right though!:P

Comment: Thank you :)     I agree it makes sense, but then I got then the problem further at            schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job,sub_list= machines_queue[counter])    The Error is : 'NameError: name 'counter' is not defined' .